# What is the grey box under account view?

Tags: support, user-accounts, information-display

When I go to the account view, I see this large, empty, grey box. What is it? Why is it there? Does it need to be there? Might it be something in the future? Could it be something in the future? Should it be deleted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's where your 'About me' values go when you edit your profile.

Comment: Then why can't it tell what it is? A dead, mute empty grey box always looks quite defective to me. Things that aren't obvious should explain themselves.

Answer (score 2):

That is your bio/About Me section.

You can edit it and fill out a short little something that you want the rest of the community to know about you.