# Filler for empty "About Me"

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, information-display

In reference to [my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22237/what-is-the-grey-box-under-account-view), I suggest that some sort of filler, or at least a label, be used to fill an otherwise conspicuously empty large grey box on account tabs with no about-me data.

Comment: Try http://imgur.com next time.

Comment: What ever you do, don't use Welbogs user page as a template.

Comment: Thanks for advertising his profile page. I saw it just now. LOL

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231112/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261510/282094

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2067/253120390a69e4052b2e14d.jpg](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2067/253120390a69e4052b2e14d.jpg)

Comment: i love it

Answer (score 4):

If you really care about your large grey box, you'll fill it with plenty of crude fiber to keep it healthy and regular.

[image]

Comment: Image isn't showing up.

Comment: I can see it. I'll try another...

Comment: Much better.  ​

Answer (score 2):

Fill it with some [Latin](http://www.lipsum.com/)!

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec libero eros. Vivamus sit amet justo lorem, at interdum sapien. In placerat quam eget nunc viverra aliquam. Duis pulvinar lacinia elit, eu aliquam neque venenatis at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum a justo metus. Quisque lorem purus, cursus sagittis facilisis a, interdum a mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet justo erat, at elementum sem. Cras in lectus nibh. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec convallis lorem at ligula pellentesque varius. Integer vitae erat turpis, ut aliquet arcu. Proin et turpis urna. Morbi eget sem dolor, vel ornare.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is what not to fill it with, as mentioned, welbog's profile. I would quote it, but got to keep things friendly. ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the User Flair could be used for filler (even though it would look like a miniature version of the page itself).

Answer (score 0):

If user has not fill this field, it should be invisible to other users. But user herself/himself can see this message with a beautiful icon (like new notepad++ icon or notepad like icon with pen):

> You can describe yourself here.

or something like that.