# Profile Page Makeover, Part 2: the Prototype

Tags: discussion, profile-page, feedback

Wow, that took longer than expected (though right around the 6-8 week mark), but we finally have a semi-working prototype of the new profile page.

#### Recap

There’s a longer explanation on [part 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover) but the gist of it is this: we’re splitting the profile into two pages:

- An “About Me” page which is what other people see when they look at your profile. **It highlights your best stuff in a way that lets users quickly get a sense of who you are and what your interests are.** For any deeper dives, you can switch over to the “Dashboard” view which houses everything else.
- A “Dashboard” page which is what you see when you go to your profile from the topbar. It highlights the stuff you need to get to fast, and hides the stuff you don’t care about (your “about me” section, your Twitter profile, etc.). For now, it is just the existing view but we’ll work on this part next.

This part is just focused on the new “About Me” page.

#### The New Stuff

<s>The prototype is only working on Stack Overflow so far, but you can try just about any profile by going to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/{id}` (note: **SO-only for now, must be logged in**). Here are some handy examples:</s>

- [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/13249/nick-craver)
- [John Resig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/6524/john-resig)
- [dr jimbob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/457571/dr-jimbob)
- [Sophia Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/3530222/sophia-taylor)

**EDIT:** The historical reloaded page is no longer visible, but it looked something like this:

[image]

We made lots of little changes based on your feedback, but the two biggest changes are the Tags and Badges sections.

#### Tags

The tags section now gives a very basic visualization of where a user does most of their posting. The section shows between 6 and 9 tags for each user, and the size is based on the percentage of posts a user has in that tag. <s>It's easiest to just look at some examples here:</s>

- [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/88656/eric-lippert) - one primary tag, six small tags
- [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/22656/jon-skeet) - one large, two medium, three small tags
- [Adam Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/519360/adam-katz) - four medium, three small
- [Sajad Lfc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/2967572/sajad-lfc) - six small

The exact rules for how the sizing is done are still in flux, so if you notice a profile that seems off, just let us know and we'll see if we can tweak the rules.

#### Badges

After the last proposal was met with at worst confusion and at best a lot of "meh", we went back to the drawing board on the badges section. We were deeply inspired by this image:

[image: Medals]

We decided we wanted to focus on two things:

1. Your most impressive badges, so they don't get lost in a pile of more common badges. If you're one of ~500 users who has earned the [Generalist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) badge on SO, you darn well deserve to show it off.
2. A visual representation of just how many badges you've earned. At some point, 1500 bronze badges becomes just another number, and it's hard to wrap your head around the sheer quantity. So we wanted to show the number visually. For new users, we wanted to feel a sense of accomplishment every time a new one shows up, and for top users, we wanted to show just how ridiculously many badges they have.

So here's the result:

<s>- [Gheorghe Bulicanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/522634) - a newish user
- [Nerdess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/393704/nerdess) - a 1k user
- [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/34397/slaks) - a top user</s>

The "Notable" section at the top lists your rarest badges, based on the number awarded on that site. The "Totals" section visualizes how many you have, and scales with your badge count. It also shows gold, silver, and bronze as different sizes to emphasize those rarer badges.

#### Other changes

We've made lots of other changes, but just a few I'll call out:

1. The "About Me" section is easier to read, fits more, and hides less.
2. Tags and Badges now use standard site styles
3. The "Top Posts" section allows you to sort by newest
4. The "Top Posts" section no longer shows badges, since it was too confusing
5. Meta activity has been added to the sidebar (it’s just a placeholder right now -- we know it doesn’t work!)

Other notes that were common questions / requests:

1. The current job and link to Careers profile are hidden for now, since they'll be optional anyway. We'll bring them back in a future version.
2. The "Apps and Projects" section will be available on all sites (probably just called "Projects"). And yes, we know this section is just an image right now -- we'll get around to implementing it soon.
3. Nothing that appears only to you on your profile, or to a moderator is implemented yet. This is just the “viewing somebody else’s profile” view.

#### Feedback

We know there are still bugs, so we’re looking more for big-picture feedback than minor bug reports. We’re still actively building the page, but wanted to get the early prototype out for feedback sooner rather than later. Let us know what you think!

Comment: This.is.sexy..!

Comment: This hasn't been enabled on the other sites yet right? I'm 404'ing trying to view my new profile on a different site.

Comment: Dang, that's a [*massive* identicon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aXpIg.png). I finally feel the need to change my profile picture...

Comment: "I don't understand this need to make everything 3x times bigger everywhere. Are people going blind?"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Looks like it's even bigger than the GitHub one.

Comment: My face is huge http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/181965

Comment: Nitpicking bastard here: Why not instead of "POSTS 102 % OF POSTS 33%" say "102 POSTS  33% OF POSTS"?

Comment: How are "impressive badges" chosen? I care more about my gold ObjC tag badge than the Marshal badge, and it's also a _far_ rarer badge.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Inverse of # granted on the site, but we exclude tag badges right now because they usually show up in the tag section. We could revisit if people think tag badges should show up there.

Comment: Any chance of letting us pick them, since the point is to show off?

Comment: @JoshCaswell not in the initial launch, but could be a feature request

Comment: @Bart, I tend to agree - we'll definitely look at that to see if it scans more naturally.

Comment: Looking good! I like the improvement overall :)

Comment: Also, just to make sure: Top Meta Posts is supposed to be canned data at this point, correct?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Correct, we haven't implemented Top Meta Posts yet, but will soon.

Comment: @DavidFullerton - Ok, awesome. As much fun as having a 191-score post is... ;)

Comment: Gravatars look absolutely horrible... well not horrible, but who needs a huge blob of random colors staring at you.  Probably will inspire me to actually upload an image.  But otherwise, looks pretty good.

Comment: Hmm, think I need to pick a higher resolution profile pic soon... http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/593627/george-duckett

Comment: @Bart - I noticed that the wording for the tag posts is now much clearer than yesterday

Comment: @Jaydles - The tag posts and percentage is much clearer now, thank you!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the heads-up @ChrisForrence

Comment: Looks awesome, I'm still interested how the apps/projects will work (mostly on other sites, but I'm still not 100% convinced on SO)

Comment: Just poking at [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/289086) I note that the top entry on 'top posts from other communities' is my really well received pseudo-rant about homework on a per-site meta.  And while I am rather proud of it, I am not sure that's what I really want to be showing off as the *top link* on that page.  Should per-site metas be excluded from that top posts section?

Comment: Im going to guess thats a picture from North Korea?

Comment: First glance, looks awesome... and [I also need to dig up a higher-res photo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/25163/).

Comment: @DavidFullerton Count me in for showing tag badges in "Notable" badges section. Gold C++ badge is about four times more rare than "Marshall" badge, for example, yet the latter is what shows up in my profile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/22656/jon-skeet The amount of badges shown at the bottom is not correct ;)

Comment: I suggest changing "View all $N questions & answers »" to "View [all] [$N1 question[s]] [&] [$N2 answer[s]] »". Now you can click view questions/answers even if there are none.

Comment: @zch - That is a good idea. Perhaps you should place it as an answer :)

Comment: Pardon me if this has already been said/asked, but are the social links below the avatar new? ([Picture](https://i.imgur.com/puJQd4r.png)) It seems they are automatically inferred from your about text, which is _very_ cool.

Comment: I like this a lot overall (:D), but I agree with others that the profile pic is way too big. You mention an emphasis on people seeing *important* info; your pic isn't exactly important. Questions, answers, badges, sure. The gravatar? Not quite so much. I'd much prefer it to be smaller.

Comment: Agree on the gravatar size; most gravatars are optimized for the default 32x32 display and don't give you anything when you supersize them.

Comment: So much wasted space... also the interface is way too minimalist for me, but I guess it is trendy to make UIs less efficient.

Comment: I just looked at my profile, and I have to agree about the avatar being WAAAAY too big. I get nothing but pixellated awfulness at that size. Gravatars are 32x32, and that's the size they should be displayed at, not one pixel bigger.

Comment: Awesome, now you can see my Trollface picture better :D http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/1517578/simon-whitehead

Comment: I really do not understand the badges thing. It just looks like a huge waste of space to me, and the uninitiated will puzzle for some time trying to figure out what it means. If you want to show the relative number of badges, why not use a number? I know, I know, it's passé, but there is a reason why counting systems have persisted for so long.

Comment: Agree with @CodyGray the badge visualization seems pointless it's just a lot of dots taking up a lot of space.

Comment: Guess I'll be ditching my gravatar now...ugly ugly

Comment: Ugly. This is not FB or Twitter.

Comment: I like the old UI better in most every way including the badges section. I'm sure I won't be the popular vote, but I think the old UI was "utilitarian" and the new one is "flashy" but less useful than the dashboard. I won't enjoy looking at the new one, and did enjoy looking at the old one when poking someone's username.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/22656/jon-skeet OMG! badges!

Comment: Please wire the '/content/user-show-reloaded-fake-mainbar.png' section.  I have Github projects that can go in there.

Comment: Do whatever you guys want to do, **just give us an option to revert to the older version**. I don't like this thing as it stands for now...

Comment: Can you give us an option to default to the dashboard?

Comment: I think my avatar is the only one which looks even better with the new profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/1091466 lol. a question: dashboard demo isn't available yet? Because it redirects to the old profile page.

Comment: Now that the tags are getting more prominent, can you first fix the problem of tag scores not being updated for days (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-scores-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse)

Comment: Sometimes the interesting thing about a tag isn't what percentage of posts are in it, but how the user ranks in the list of top users for that tag.

Comment: @brasofilo `sexy != easy_to_live_with`

Comment: There's no 'Reputation Graph' right??

Comment: Not going to make the profile pictures round?

Comment: +1 for redesigning the profiles. looks good

Comment: As someone whose involvement thus far has only been about 4 months, I've just gotten used to finding what I'm looking for in the current dashboard. For me an option to use the old version would be invaluable. It appears I'm not the only one who feels this way. All things considered I'm more interested in a clear, concise view of data than the type of flash thrown up on Facebook or other social sites.

Comment: Why put 1/2 the info in 2x the space?  Also, being *deeply inspired* by the Korean People's Army is uninspiring, to say the least.

Comment: I really like the look of these changes!  Any idea when they will take effect across the network?

Comment: image is way too big for most avatar resolutions.Did you start the average avatar resolution before you decide the size of the image on the left?

Comment: Idea for displaying badges is not so good, will make a mess on a long run...

Comment: Are we allowed to upload animated gifs for profile pics? Because I want to upload an [ambigram](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAmbigram&ei=Pwh3U7eHJJaPuASXwIKoBA&usg=AFQjCNHA3WxG7r_6Chnsuqml-YLgesAleQ&sig2=Wo12UgQnmYDpgLIAqfmTJQ) and people don't understand them unless they see them in [action](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/3bBclD2x22YBs3V37QMda_vjDHGjqI9eVRt9-W9wugE=s500-no).

Comment: @mcalex I believe they were inspired to *avoid* recreating that image. Instead of a sea of a billion badges, highlight the ones that matter.

Comment: Is there any chance that we'll see some Favorites menu love in any of your mockups?

Comment: When will these changes be reflected or when could i see my new profile/

Comment: works for me...

Comment: Too much white-space, especially in the about me section, double spaced lines are too much.

Comment: I don't like 'Q' and 'A' balloons -- they clickability isn't enough obvious.

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: @DJDavid98 Shh, don't wake it up. Let this embarrassing incident be forgotten. (Especially since Jeremy T moved on.)

Comment: @Thursday Who is Jeremy T? And I'm personally positive towards any sort of change to the profile page, and taking some user suggestions into account, this could actually be beneficial.

Comment: @DJDavid98 [Jeremy T](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/202998/jeremy-t) was a Project Manager at SE primarily responsible for the UX, he posted part 1 of the redesign.

Comment: @DavidFullerton should we interpret the lack of response here as a "this is no longer happening"?

Comment: @Stijn No, it's still happening. You could interpret the lack of response as general despair over ever finishing. Mostly what happened is that other urgent projects (e.g. quality on SO) jumped in front of this one.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Thank you for the reply. By all means take your time for this, it's just handy to keep the community in the loop :)

Comment: Test link is down. Is that indicative of anything in particular?

Comment: Any news on the progress of this ?

Comment: @DavidFullerton Cant view the prototype for my profile. was it removed ?

Comment: To prevent confusion and wrong answers, I've closed this as dupe of the updated post by Oded. Hope it's fine by you @DavidFullerton and of course if not, feel free to Reopen.

Comment: it would help if there was a generalized estimate of how long it took for a new user to earn a specific badge... then you can just whether it is really worth the effort

Answer (score 159):

## Badge popup

As I commented on [Josh's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype#comment759322_231117), I'd love to see something like this:

[image]

As a concession to the case where you have a *lot* of badges, particularly bronze, how about something like this:

[image]

---

### Update: [I made a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8RVTd/2/)

I've updated this so all that needs to be sent over is a list of badge ids. The HTML is then expanded from the list.

Comment: This example shows a Legendary badge and an Epic badge.  Given that you can't get Legendary without first getting Epic, I'm not sure that Epic is all that notable when you also have Legendary (though it is worth showing if the user does not have Legendary yet).  I've got both; I was debating whether to raise this as a separate issue/answer.  Also, do you consider Gold 'subject' badges where there are small numbers of the badge awarded as noteworthy?  (For example, only two people have a gold Unix badge at the moment; that's arguably more noteworthy than having both Legendary and Epic.)

Comment: The bronze badges can get so tiny, do you really want a popup when you hover over each one? It would be very hard to hover over a particular bronze badge because of its size on the screen.

Comment: @cupcake The purpose of this view is to highlight the magnitude of badges you have earned. I imagine mousing over the bronze badges with the popup would be very satisfying...

Comment: Love the art and fonts smoothing ! +1

Comment: Maybe just do the popup for gold badges? In this example there are 1500 silver and bronze badges. At (ballpark figure) 20 bytes per badge that would be 30kb more traffic and probably more in the page for something which almost nobody will use.

Comment: @Raidri See my further suggestion. This way at most only one popup per badge type would need to be loaded.

Comment: @fredley Yes, that could work, but I am still not sure, if it's worth it for that many badges.

Comment: @Raidri The point is to feel awesome about how many badges you have. Seeing this on my profile would make me feel awesome :D

Comment: I wonder how big the html is going to be for this when someone has thousands of different badges...

Comment: @PlasmaHH See my comment above. With the way I've got it you'd need at most one popup (-sworth of html) per badge.

Comment: @PlasmaHH you're not the only one wondering that - this probably can't be done for technical reasons alone

Comment: @NickCraver :-(

Comment: I think it's because what you see in the profile is just an image.

Comment: 1) While this works with the SO badge design, it doesn't quite work on other sites (you don't want a large rectangle for [badges on TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges) for instance). 2) The whole idea of showing the magnitude of badges you've earned: Damn, are we here for earning useless stuff or for helping each other? 3) The information shown in the hover is quite useless: you'd have to hover over each dot to get any relevant information.

Comment: @NickCraver [How about if it works something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/8RVTd/)

Comment: @fredley we *really* don't want to have 1 HTML element per badge because it will slow down the browser. More plausible would be to download the list as JSON on mouseover and then just do some math to figure out what you're hovering over.

Comment: @DavidFullerton or generate the HTML from the JSON maybe?

Comment: @DavidFullerton [How about this?](http://jsfiddle.net/8RVTd/2/)

Comment: What problem would this solve? I doubt anyone goes like "I wonder what badge that is, on line 16, row 42". It doesn't really matter which badge is which and to browse them, the list view is way more useful. I admit though, hovering to get a tooltip was the first thing I tried when I saw those tiny badges. I think I just did this because almost every abridged data on se has tooltips.

Comment: I agree with kapep (and not because of my own feelings about the badges visualisation) If I want to see what the badges are, there are far more practical ways to do it. This suggestion has fun value, but in terms of outright practicality, I'm not sure what purpose it serves.

Comment: Fair enough then :) (and congrats on the badge!)

Comment: @kapep I agree it's probably not useful for the tiny bronze badges, but I could easily see mousing over a handful of gold badges to see what somebody has.

Comment: @fredley that looks pretty good. I think we'll do something like this, though maybe not right away since there are so many other pieces to get done.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I know the feeling, happy the suggestion was useful though!

Comment: @DavidFullerton and fredly though you shouldn't make the popup accept mouse events: http://jsfiddle.net/8RVTd/7/. Hover over a badge in the bottom row and then move the cursor up. Try the same with the example in the answer to see the difference. (Only difference is `pointer-events: none` on the popout).

Answer (score 114):

[image]

## DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING | KEEP IT LIKE IT IS | NO MAKEOVERS

Comment: Tempted to upvote just for the gif...

Comment: I personally agree with this answer. The new profile page looks completely useless to me. It shows a few "top" badges and tags.. The old profile did that just fine while keeping all the other important information I want right there, easy to access. Yeah the profile page could use a redesign, but why remove functionality?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Nobody said anything about removing functionality. Please read the post; it outlines the plan.

Comment: @balpha `/s/remove/move`. I must say though, the *design* factor looks great. I also like that I get the important stuff when I click on myself, but I still don't like how most of the important stuff I want to see on a profile is hidden under "dashboard". But, I suppose I will get used to it :-/

Comment: @ɥʇǝS That's valuable feedback -- make a case for it in an answer here.

Comment: @balpha [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231192/203389). Forgive me if some of them are just nitpicks.

Comment: [+1] as I agree for the simple reason that it’s never a good idea change a “winning“ concept.

Comment: I downvoted though the GIF is hilarious :) I simply don't agree that change is bad. Sure, the prototype can be improved but it's heading in the right direction

Comment: +1 Add his voice, boy...

Comment: @balpha Shush, removing functionality and making things that do a function harder to do, basically the same thing. I don't care what badges someone has if I want to find out about any gems of interesting Qs they have.... atm it works great :)

Comment: You know when you go to some page on some site, and it has been completely pointlessly changed, redesigned, madeover. And you think "wow it is so annoying when they completely pointlessly change, redesign, makeover a page like that." That is exactly what you're looking at here. it is an ABSOLUTE CLICHÉ of utterly, totally, fully, completely, hopelessly pointless change, redesign, makeover.

Comment: God, this is hilarious.. You made my day.. :P

Answer (score 105):

**tag section**

The new tag section has three fewer tags and takes up nearly twice as much area. It would be nice if it could be condensed while still retaining some of the interesting information (such as **score** in tag). Since space is an issue, and people are already used to the format, I think keeping the old score display still works here.

To make it fit, perhaps cut the line-height and the height definitions from `.tag-container` and cut the padding in half. The tag area takes up a lot of space in my opinion, and it really doesn't need to be that spacious (unless there is more planned to go in there in which case disregard the spacial note).

To me, this just looks cleaner

[image]

than this:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say it looks cleaner, but I'd much rather have the score there than either the number or percentage of posts.

Comment: Please leave the score in there.

Comment: We talked about score, but struggled since they don't "add up". But we'll take another look.  On the number/size, they key goal here was to *visually* convey when some tags dominate a user's activity at a glance, without depending much on the numbers/text.  The final version will have more font size difference between the three sizes, which is why the boxes are taller than seems necessary.

Comment: @Jaydles - For the size, as noted, if there is a plan then disregard that :) For the score, personally it does not seem out of order if it is included but the tags are sorted by "% of posts". I can understand that ordering. However, it would be nice if the score could be included, even if it isn't the basis of the sort order.

Comment: @Jaydles - Also, for the "% of posts metric", it seems that my first 4 tags account for 108% of my activity. There may be a bug there. Ah right, sometimes they overlap - nevermind, although slightly confusing.

Comment: @TravisJ, we're trying to convey that we want you to give 110% out there, champ! You're almost there!

Comment: @Jaydles, maybe if not the tag score, then at least a circle for tag badges? (I do really wish there were a score though...)

Comment: Maybe the tag box could have a bronze/silver/gold border if you have the appropriate badge?

Comment: @Jaydles the percentages won't add up for the same reason...I'd much rather score was kept as well, it's much more useful. Currently it says I posted a ton of things in this tag...ok fine, but of what quality? Without score it's *only* a volume indicator.

Comment: @NickCraver, stop showing off, you! Okay, I'm sold in theory - we'll talk to the designers to see what our options are.

Comment: Yes please, put back the score. It's a much more valid indicator of knowledge than the raw number of answers that bear that tag.

Answer (score 100):

There doesn't seem to be a way to get to [a list of all my badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell?tab=badges) at the moment.

There's also some bits that seem like they should be clickies (a.k.a. "links"), but are just images.

[image]

Link to the badge list, sorted by classes, or (maybe better), a page for each class.

---

[image]

There's a lot of dead space here. At least the "Posts NNN" text should be a link, I think, to the same thing as the tag image to the left. But why not the whole box?

---

[image]

There's a link for these right below the table, yes, but these Q and A bubbles look like filter controls, especially being next to the Votes/Newest sort buttons.

---

[image]

The heading should link to my full list of badges, and it would be cool if clicking on each of the groups led to a page displaying that badge class.

Comment: I appreciate your visual retelling of the journey you took searching for something to click. (I think the lack of a "view all" link for badges was just an oversight; we pretty much were going for every section having a link to a page with more detail.)

Comment: I figured there'd be a link to the badge list eventually, @Laura, but it seemed wise to mention it just in case.

Comment: Agree, those should all be clickable -- except maybe the badges header since the other headers aren't clickable right now.

Comment: Can I add another `SHOW ME` suggestion? When I hover over the badges in *TOTALS*, I'd like to see a little popout of which badge that is, and maybe when I earned it. Pretty please?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of something like that, too, @fredley. Why not post an answer?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Done!

Comment: In the tags, should it be noted if someone is in the Top N (e.g. Top 25 or Top 30) contributors in that tag?

Comment: When I click on the A/Q icons, the view changes to show only answers or questions, but I can't get back to showing all posts unless I refresh the page. Also, when you hover over the badge counts at the top, they change color slightly, indicating you can click them. If you can't click them, remove the animation.

Comment: [obligatory commendation for freehand red circles]

Answer (score 80):

Please, please, *please* do not make the profile pic that huge! I literally winced and produced a pained sound when I clicked on my test profile page. It looks horrible, completely over-sized and just needlessly occupies space.

I could count the pores on poor [Slak's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/34397/slaks) face and could easily count the pixels on [nerdess'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/393704/nerdess). We have had various discussions over the years with the SE team politely explaining that no, this is not a social media site but a Q&A site. Why this sudden urge to make our profiles appear like facebook?

Everything else is much better than version 1, I think you might be on to something here but just please make that pic smaller.

Comment: Yes, please.  We generated our gravatars with the current usage needs in mind; not all of them scale well to such a large size.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: That's not really a very good argument, though, since the only way to *get* people to choose avatars that work at larger sizes is to start showing them at such size.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen why should we need to? Do you really expect the millions of SE users to all update their avatars? I don't _want_ a huge photo dominating my profile and I certainly wouldn't want to force users to change their pics like this. Ideally, this type of makeover should be painless for the user and not require any input/reaction from him/her. In any case, my main consideration is aesthetic, I find the huge pic to be out of proportion and ugly.

Comment: @terdon: I have no strong opinions either for or against big avatars, but if we *do* want them, this is the only way to get them. The only way to increase the resolution of a (non-autogenerated) avatar is for the user to upload a bigger image, and the only effective way to encourage users to upload high-resolution avatars is to start using them in a context where high-resolution images look better. Otherwise, if we don't want to "force users to change their pics like this", we'll be locked in to the current maximum avatar size (as shown on the current-style profile page) for all eternity.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen agreed, and that's precisely what I want. I see no reason to increase the avatar size, it just causes extra work (we all need to update/modify ours) and I at least find it horribly ugly. So why do it at all? It seems to be creating problems and solving none. The current size is fine.

Comment: @terdon: If you feel that bigger avatars are intrinsically "horribly ugly" and worse than small ones, then that's a valid argument against them. However, the extra work is not; if bigger avatars are even *slightly* better than small ones in any way, then the continual benefit of having them will *eventually* overcome the one-time cost of switching to them.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree with terdon that the humongous image is ugly.  But if you want to encourage a behavior change, you can start by offering an *option*.  Don't assume that everybody is using photos that they shrunk down & it's trivial to make a new version from the original; some existing gravatars are the size they are and won't get bigger.  Is it worth making millions of profiles ugly just because somebody thinks bigger is better, globally?  Remember that some of these gravatars convey identity across the Internet, so "just do something else" isn't free.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: How would you "offer an option" here? Design two different layouts for the profile page, one for small avatars and one for large? Use the old profile page design for users with small avatars? Or just show a small avatar surrounded by a huge blank space?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen many options: 1) Leave the avatar as is, why make it larger? 2) Allow the user to resize as desired 3) Allow users to choose between the current and a larger size, make it an opt-in. I don't see why any of these apart from 1 would be useful but it is certainly possible to give options.

Comment: I dig the new size - mine is after all a landscape view tho.

Comment: @terdon: My point is that the proposed design is based on a certain avatar size. If you change it (or make it user-adjustable), you either need to redo the whole design or leave a whole bunch of white space. Yeah, I think we can all agree that [the avatar here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8DgTD.png) doesn't look very good at that size, but honestly, would [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DGMJq.png) (or even [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yPeM5.png)) be any better?

Comment: All the other places the profile image is shown are very tiny.  It's already hard to pick a profile image that looks good tiny in chat *and* as big as it is on the current profile page.

Comment: There is one compromise option, one of the few things that didn't earn too much flak when Flickr overhauled their UI last year:  if the profile pic is smaller than the display space, it shows up as a normal-resolution inset on top of a pixelated version.  (I kind of liked the effect, and [haven't changed mine yet](https://www.flickr.com/photos/abellamyroyds/).)

Comment: This isn't the only place that uses Gravatars, so you ***can't*** use them at a size that Gravatar doesn't support.

Comment: Some numbers may help. Gravatar supports from 1px to 2048px (though they do warn most users have smaller images). The new profile uses 256px; the old 128px. So the new profile is 2× what it was, 3.2× Gravatar's default and yet only 1/8th of the maximum. Life _would_ be better if Gravatar supported multiple images per address so you could specify one image for 128px and below and another for 129px and above. However if they were going to allow that they'd probably already allow different images at different ratings. I guess "Globally Recognised avatar" means "the same everywhere" whatever size.

Answer (score 59):

## Top Tags

The first profile I looked at was my own (obviously ;-):

[image: My boring tags]

Two things that stick out:

1. No percentages.

   Presumably that's since I have 205 posts and so my top tag is < 15% or somesuch.
2. [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) is [odd here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694).

   My [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1438+%5Bposix%5D) just happened to be to a really popular question. (I guess I should be glad the algorithm didn't pick up my answer to a [die](/questions/tagged/die) question.) **This set of tags fails to highlight my best stuff.** If there were a way to eliminate secondary tags and focus on specific languages, that would help make this section more meaningful. [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), [unix](/questions/tagged/unix), and [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) seem less meaningful than [c](/questions/tagged/c), [lua](/questions/tagged/lua), and [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) in my opinion. I don't really know how to separate then algorithmically, however.

## A user's tags are kinda boring

But the far larger problem is that tags don't tell a good story in isolation. This section reminds me of the terrible ["Skills" section of resumes](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/list/fl/computer-programming-skills.htm). It doesn't tell anyone anything useful about me as a programmer. If the tags were listed next to each "Top Post" we wouldn't need the "Top Tags" section at all. Since this cuts off the bottom of my "about me" section, it should be awesome. Instead, it just gets in the way of the good stuff below.

We already get this right in other places:

- [Careers 2.0 profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jericson):

  [image: Leader board.]

  [image: Experience]
- [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1083/jon-ericson?tab=top):

  [image: Top question]

I think a traditional [tag cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) tells a better story. To me, this looks like me:

[image: My tag cloud]

All I did was grab the tag set from all of my questions and questions I've answered ([using this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/192364/tag-frequency?opt.textResults=true)) and pasted the result into a cloud tag generator. (The one I picked strips punctuation and single-letter words, so `c#` and `.net` aren't displayed properly.)

Here's [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy), who knows *way* more about Perl than I do:

[image: brian d foy]

The story is more interesting because you can "read" it at a glance. brian is an expert in Perl and I dabble in a variety of languages including Perl. Notice that this doesn't take into account *anything but frequency*. With tag scores and badges, a visualization could be substantially more rich. Perhaps tags could be colored gold, silver and bronze for users that have the equivalent badge in that tag.

It strikes me that 6-9 tags displayed with dry statistics lack the context provided by 25-50 tags displayed according to frequency. My tag cloud accurately tells you how often I thought about the POSIX spec (essentially never) while answering questions. brian d foy's tells you that the books he listed in his "about me" are worth buying. Can you tell the story of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/3530222/sophia-taylor)?

[image: Sophia Taylor]

**Either list tags with "Top Posts", find a dramatically better visualization of tags, or move "Top Tags" *way down* on the page.**

Comment: Gotta think about some of your other suggestions, but the problem with the ones you highlight as being better in the current profile is that while you're right that they contain *more* information, they only convey *any* to someone who commits to parsing a very long list of items - if you give people two bullets, they probably read 2.  If you give them 100, it's better if they *really* care, because they get 98 more pieces of info, but if they were looking for a snapshot, they actually get 2 fewer, because they wind up reading none.

Comment: @Jaydles: The other displays of user's tags are better because they include more _context_ and not simply more information. Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert know a hell of a lot about C#. But the tag display tells that story rather poorly. Show me the tags on their top posts and you wouldn't need to have a separate tag section. Adding tag score would help a tiny bit, but it would still be 6-9 "skills" without any real way to contextualize. A [tag cloud](https://www.librarything.com/tagmirror/jericson&size=100) seems like a better approach. (I.e., just the tag name sized by importance.)

Comment: Regarding the tags for that brand-new user: Those will get special treatment until they're above a certain threshold; that justn't implemented yet.

Comment: You have 1 posts in [posix]. *cough* giant S *cough*

Comment: @michaelb958: I _might_ have hidden a link in my answer... ;-)

Comment: -1 I would not want a tag cloud on my profile. Whilst they can be variably effective if used to express the appropriate data and implemented well, they're inherently extremely ugly and inelegant. There's probably a better way.

Comment: every thing but the tag cloud :P

Comment: _...can you tell the story about [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/3530222/sophia-taylor)?..._ Yes I can, she likes to go out, while not behind a computer!!! XD

Comment: @Awal Garg: That's actually an important point: the tag display often shortens long "about me" sections which implies that tags tell a user's story better than they do themselves. I'm not convinced the current visualization does. Tag clouds get much closer to doing so.

Comment: +1 for the tag cloud! Great idea, intuitive and instantly understandable.

Comment: Tag clouds are not fashionable at the moment, but they do a great job of getting information across very quickly and intuitively.

Comment: Tag clouds don't work very well for a number of reasons: 1. Unless the additional data is included in title attributes, visually impaired/non-style based users don't see any difference in the data. 2. Jon's last example shows a classic issue - one tag massively outweighs the others, which makes them hard to read. 3. Comparing users tags is harder - the sizes are effectively subjective as they are sized relative to the user, rather than objectively size compared to everyone.

Comment: @Zhaph - Ben Duguid: These problems are likely fixable by someone designing a custom tag cloud for this purpose. You might notice I played around with number of tags and image size to get a result that was pleasing to me. This would need to be  automated. In particular, the last example used _all_ of the user's tags, even though only one of them was repeated. Also, I used the "medium" Imgur size for the two users with < 10k of reputation.

Answer (score 49):

I think **the rep count gets a bit lost on the right hand side**, the 'reading trail' usually starts from the left and moves down.

Reading direction in blue, rep in red:

[image]

Possible alternatives:

- Rep next or underneath the name
- Some highlighting or weight for the number that would drag attention to the right side of the layout
- Rep as an overlay on avatar?

Comment: I'm curious about what would show up in eye tracking, now...

Comment: I agree with Yisela, it took me some time to find the rep.

Comment: How about rep under image, like the old style?

Comment: I like the overlay on the image idea

Comment: "Member of 1 Stack Exchange Communitie **`s`**"

Comment: You're right - rep was stranded. New version has rep under the avatar.  Good call.

Answer (score 47):

I would rather see this:

> [image: some notable and recent badges]

Than this:

> [image: a couple of noteworthy badges]

Or at the very least, I *would* like to see the 'recent' section. The visualisation itself doesn't add much value for me, and the 'recent' section is far more valuable.

I get what you're up to here with the visualisation, and I understand you want to give us a sense of scale for *just how many* 1468 thingies is - because at that scale it becomes just a number. The dots don't actually add all that much for me, though: seeing all the dots there makes me think "that's a lot of dots", which is not much different to thinking "that's a big number". The sense of scale is lost to me either way. I do see that 641 silver thingies is a lot more than 66 gold thingies, but I already knew that.

(Maybe it's different for others, but the numbers themselves have more impact for me than the dots. No lie, I'm *actually surprised* those are a whole 66 gold dots: it doesn't look like nearly that many until I count them!)

What's far more important to me is *what the badges are that they have.* Hence being able to see a list of their recent badges, similar to what we currently have, is important to keep around.

Comment: I agree 200%...

Comment: Agreed, and also, the total number of badges is already on the profile page next to reputation, we don't need the same info twice.

Comment: The funny thing is that, to me, the dots seem less significant than the numbers. I look at the dots and think, *Ooh look, a bunch of dots*, but when I glance over to the numbers, suddenly I know how many badges this person has. The dots do nothing useful for me.

Comment: +1 If they force us with that badge scale thingy, I would use Adblock plus to disable that tomato plantation.

Comment: I don't hang around meta often enough to have the 125 reputation needed to downvote this idea. The proposed re-design is much more informative than the old one. And looks good for show-off !

Comment: @chronodekar What is more informative in my user profile having freckles in 3 colours over having three numbers, and then reasonable information in place of the freckles? And if you are here to show off, then something is wrong, sorry.

Comment: @tohecz I'm here to advance my intelligence. And by nature, enjoy showing it off!

Comment: hmmm, interesting juxtaposition between *advancing intelligence* and switching numbers and words for colors and pictures because they're *much more informative*.

Comment: @mcalex colors and pictures help (ever looked at a graph?), though I don't think they do in this circumstance

Comment: I know they help, but when you want *more* information, ie, once you've grokked the picture, you go to the numbers and words.

Answer (score 35):

Please don't take this as a negative stance to what is being accomplished here. Your continuing drive to try to innovate is much appreciated, but to me the benefits seem to be a little on the 'light' side.

### 1. Tags

It's great having more information such as the amount and percent of total posts a tag represents, but this means nothing if you just post rubbish, and post a lot.

Instead, (or in addition) we should have tag score as well as the percentile you are within the tag vs all other users.

Also, having only a few tags on display gives the wrong impression. If all your tag post amounts are separated by a single post, does this display make sense? **NO**. Maybe on the left have the top 5 tags in a table with scores, then a collection of other tags in some space to the right. Or the current list of top 10, but with more metrics.

> **[TLDR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR):**
>
> **Problem:** Unconvincing use of space, potentially unhelpful metrics
>
> **Solution:** Keep tags the same size, display a (sortable) list with information, including tag score and percentile of all users for that tag. Do this
>   for maybe the top 10 tags, similar to at present.

### 2. Communities / Top Posts from other communities / Top Meta posts

I'm not sure whether it's just me, and I know the current profile page has a list of accounts..but I often have to provide a link to my Stack Overflow account page to potential employers, because increasingly *they are asking for it*.

This is because I work in this field, the field they are interested in.

I don't want them to see an opinion I post or protracted debate I get into on meta. I also don't want them to see I also post on other Stack Exchange sites - I'm trying to present a view of myself about programming, not how to invade and do unholy things to unwitting players on Dark Souls. I'm aware this is all traceable via the network profile section, which is fine- I just don't like it being so easily accessible.

Only today I was on https://money.stackexchange.com/, and I saw a pretty senior member of the Stack Overflow community had posted a question about debt. Why on earth would they want a prospective employer looking at their Stack Overflow profile immediately have this pop up in their face?? In honesty it would be great to have the option to turn off any membership of other sites from being visible - for fear of stopping people posting on them for fear all their dirty laundry is getting aired in all the wrong places.

I'm aware there is Careers 2.0 for the careers aspect, but it, er, links back to your profile page anyway, so the issue still exists. My Stack Overflow profile should be totally Stack Overflow centric - the rest of my Stack Exchange interactions should be on the metrics (Dashboard) page, if present at all.

> **TLDR:**
>
> **Problem:** I have a real issue with these lists. Stack Overflow is for programming, my profile is for Stack Overflow, and should reflect this. Employers
>   are asking for a Stack Overflow profile link, why would I want them to see my
>   posts in Arqade?
>
> **Solution:** We already have a network profile link, I can trace through my other interactions through this. Alternatively add a new
>   tab under the dashboard section for 'network activity'

### 3. Top Posts

**Questions and Answers should be kept separate**

They are fundamentally different things, keep them apart. They are the two sides of the site. This is not a forum site which you can reduce every item to just being a 'post'. Typically people looking at a profile care about one or another, they should be easily identifiable, and at the moment it's a total muddle.

Also, the link at the bottom then says *'View all 908 questions & answers »'* with separate links on 'questions' and 'answers'...which means you aren't able to view *all* 908...only one or the other type. This makes no sense.

> **TLDR:**
>
> **Problem:** This is a Q & A site, not a forum, users don't have posts; they ask questions or provide answers, which are two fundamentally different things, and should not be mixed together. I view a profile and want to immediately see one or the other clearly distinguished and identifiable
>
> **Solution:** Keep separate sections for questions and answers. By combining the two, you obfuscate what people are trying to find.

### 4. Badges, Apps & Projects, Missing Bounties/Votes Content

For the badges, it isn't obvious what notable means, even with the '1 of only..' text. What if it isn't notable to me? I'd be inclined to list the 'most recent 3'.

I'm also not convinced I need yet another place I have to maintain a list of my applications and projects. If this can somehow hook into Careers 2.0 then great... Otherwise, it feels like a bit of a duplication of purpose between the two sites.

Not only this, but we now have less information than we had before, and where are the bounties and votes sections? For some users, these are particularly interesting (even if only for seeing how close you are to the 600 votes on questions badge).

> **TLDR:**
>
> **Problem:** Content has been replaced with less interesting or less relevant content. No bounties or votes sections. Duplication with Careers 2.0 page with projects area, Badges section not really interesting any more - usability replaced with looks.
>
> **Solution:** Keep an area for bounties and votes. If we have a projects section, ensure it can be linked to a Careers 2.0 page, change notable badges with most recent / notable sortable list, dont use badge graphics for each badge, just have badge x number.

Comment: #3 so much. I answer more questions than I ask, but that doesn't mean I'm not proud of the questions that I do ask. Show as many top questions as answers.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat +2 for Dark Souls II

Comment: +1 for all the points. And I'm especially curious what will show instead of Projects on other SE sites. Because SE is not SO/Carrers for many of us.

Comment: +1 for everything, but especially for #2. I have enough reputation on [The Workspace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) that it is shown in my "Communities" section, with a few questions being in my "Top Posts from other Communities". I do not want potential employers being presented with a link to browse my Workspace questions and answers, and viewing how I handle things like salary negotiations, workplace conflicts, quitting my old job, finding a new job, or possibly even questions about them.

Comment: #2 Absolutely.  Bringing in the top badges to show off your most impressive achievements and top tags where a user does most of their posting is inconsistent with chucking in something from somewhere entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 34):

Per [balpha's request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype/231134?noredirect=1#comment759413_231134) I've tried to expand my concerns into an answer.

My main problem with the redesign is: It moves a lot of the information I want on a user's profile under "dashboard" and/or makes it harder to get to.  Here's a brief overview of everything the new profile page has, and the stuff it's missing I think it should have:

- Newest questions and answers
- Top questions and answers

I really prefer the two column layout, one for questions, one for answers, but I suppose I can get used to one column. However, it would be really good if you could make the little icon that differentiates between question and answer more.. obvious? Currently I have to look at it really carefully to tell if it's a question or an answer.

- Badges

The new profile really doesn't have this, I can see their top badges, and I can see their total badges, but that's it. There isn't even a way for me to see a list of all their badges, much less recent ones. This was already addressed in [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231117/203389) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231129/203389) and I like what they propose.

- Votes

Sometimes I am interested in a user's voting specs/habits. There isn't anything relating to votes on the new page what.so.ever.

- Reputation

This isn't a biggie, but hey, shouldn't there be *something* to do with reputation on the new page? I could care less about tags, but that's thrown right into my face! (more on this later).

- Tags

I go to a user's profile when I want to look at their tag data, top tags, tags they have a score of 5 in and just tags in general. The new mockup has some interesting specs, but it doesn't show score or utilize space well.. at all. As [another answer noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231122/203389) this could really be improved. Right now there is just too much space, and it looks ugly.

- Bounties

I feel this is a big one. There's absolutely nothing about bounties. I think the new profile should *at least* show active bounties.

- Top posts from other communities

I feel this shouldn't be there. If I want to see a user's network activity I will go to their network profile. Right now it's taking up space that more important things could be occupying. Like bounties, reputation, votes, etc.

- Apps and projects

<strike>I think this is a cool idea and inclusion, but it isn't going to be much use outside of the programming sites (my understanding is it only ties into GitHub, did I miss something?)</strike> ([the projects section will let you use arbitrary links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231291/203389)). I suggest you put it on a flip-card like thing  with "top posts":

[image]

That will make more space for *important* things. Or, if you're feeling up to it, make it customizable per site. We could have Launchpad Repos on AU, All Recipes recipes on cooking, etc.

- Accounts

Often times I have quick access to a user's account on my main site and I use that as a jumping off place to get to another of their accounts (for whatever reason). This is actually well implemented, and I like it, although swapping the "network profile" with "more accounts" like you did will take some getting used to.  Also, long site names could use some tweaking ;)

[image]

- Top meta posts

This is really cool, and a great way to expand "Meta profile" into something a little more useful.

- Mod buttons

Please tell me you didn't move all my mod buttons under the dashboard...

---

### tl;dr

While the overall design looks nice, it feels like most of the functionality has been made harder to get to, and the idea of "two" profile pages (dashboard/profile) makes it feel... awkward and duplicated.

Comment: Agree with nearly all suggestions here.  I don't agree that "Top posts from other communities" shouldn't be there -- it's nice to know at a glance if a user who doesn't have a lot of rep on this site is active on another one, versus a total new user.  But I do like the idea of making that section share space with the "Projects" section.  That also provides some content for that space if the user hasn't added any projects to the profile.

Comment: I like "Top posts from other communities", I like "Apps and projects", and I *really* like the fact that this is being split into two pages.  The first page you go to if you want to be narcissistic or see what you look like to others; the second page you go to if you want to do anything with your account.  Other than that I agree with this answer, but confused about whether I should upvote due to partial agreement...

Comment: @Goos I have no problem with either of those, but I take issue with the fact that they are taking up space more important stuff should be occupying.

Answer (score 30):

[image: Tags]

Why is there so much blank space? Why don't all of them have percentages? Why is [html](/questions/tagged/html) so much bigger than [css](/questions/tagged/css) when it only has 3% more posts?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it's because it's still the top tag - reguardless of by how much.

Comment: @AnonJr: Well, I have over twice as many [css] posts as [html] posts but they're on the same row...

Comment: @Bolt don't know... I was making an educated guess based on a brief look.

Answer (score 30):

There's rather much blank space.

Current left, proposed right:

[image: highlighted blanks]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with whitespace if it makes it easier to visually parse & understand the information being presented.

Comment: @David I agree, but when the padding between sections is thrice the section heading font height, I think things have gone too far.

Comment: @DavidFullerton - with the greatest respect saying there is 'nothing wrong' would mean nobody had a problem with it, which this post kind of contradicts. I think you mean it has merit.

Comment: @DavidFullerton and vice versa

Comment: @SW4 A little late but "saying there's nothing wrong would mean nobody had a problem with it" is not true. There can be nothing wrong with it and people still take offense to it. Those people are just wrong.

Comment: @TylerH - if people have a problem, there is something wrong, whether fundamentally or perceptually - both are valid within a community and if presented en-masse should be addressed.

Comment: @SW4 If you include lack of understanding/knowledge on how something works in "something wrong", then yes I guess you are correct. And of course I agree that concerns should still always be addressed.

Answer (score 24):

Can I choose the posts that appear in *Top Posts from other Communities*? (sidenote: [capital O for Other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized)), or at least hide ones I [don't want](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160556/which-doge-represents-what-number/160558#160558) there, similar to how I can choose what gets displayed on my Careers 2.0 profile?

Also, should Meta.SE posts be included in the list? Meta posts and meta votes are rather different, so maybe should be included in the Top Meta Posts section rather than other communities?

Comment: About the second paragraph: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype?page=1&tab=votes#comment760733_231285

Comment: much upvote very doge...

Comment: @Rachel so regret

Comment: But seriously, I gave this a +1 because there are times that I do not want my activity on one site broadly published across other sites, or have specific questions from those sites showing up on my SO profile page. For example, I've asked quite a few questions on [The Workspace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/), and if I'm showing a potential employer my SO profile page, I don't want them seeing my posts from there regarding salary negotiations, co-worker conflicts, or how to quit my job.

Answer (score 21):

I like what you have done so far. I think it would also be good if we could see the awarded tag-badges against the top tags.

[image: Tag Badge]

Answer (score 19):

**badge section**

If the new badge display is going to be showy then let it be. It needs to have more than 3 badges for those who have earned more than 3 awesome badges.

Jon Skeet comes to mind, mostly because of the example in this post. He doesn't seem to have much more than the other users because only 3 "notable ones" are listed. Sure, there is a list of bulleted badges below but to the eye they are small enough that they sort of blend into a lot of noise. The 3 are the main ones that get noticed, and almost every user has at least 3 badges.

Did you know Jon Skeet has 44 gold tag badges? While his zone of badge bullets below is impressive, there is nothing else down there and more than likely users wont scroll just to see how far the badge bullets go. It would be nice if there was a way to work in at least a few more of his impressive badge work. I am not sure what that would entail, but 3 doesn't seem to really represent the "notable" section enough in my opinion.

Also, some of the tag badges are kind of notable, especially when you were the only one to get them

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Staff feedback in comments: the project section will allow arbitrary links! :D

---

> The "Apps and Projects" section will be available on all sites (probably just called "Projects"). And yes, we know this section is just an image right now -- we'll get around to implementing it soon.

Thank you. But this needs to be implemented correctly if it's offered to other sites, and that should mean the following:

## The projects section *must* allow arbitrary links.

Currently it just displays github, and it seems that was the original plan. But if expanded to other sites, it must allow us to link to whatever site we want: a tumblr link, a github, our personal domain at example.com. Otherwise it's going to be not very useful, because most other sites won't really have a reliable central project hub.

For perspective, this was going to be SO-only in the first version of this profile page redesign. We requested it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226180/152515) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226242/152515), and the first of those links was the 5th-ranked answer. I'll quote my comment from there, which gathered 16 unicorn points:

> +1 Please make this available to other sites, and don't limit us to whitelisted hubs. On RPG.SE, which is not techincal/programming, there are people developing their own RPG systems, and I'm working on a tabletop simulator. All of these projects are as significant to us as github projects are to a developer, and none of them have one single hub site in common. Arbitrary links might come with spam concerns, but we can already provide an arbitrary link in our 'website' field.

You may get people promoting their own sites, and I'll be linking to my own tabletop simulator site & blog when it's launched, but if those sites are our projects, that's kind of the point! If you're concerned about people providing inappropriate links, like a Kings of Chaos recruiter link on Arqade or a sales referral page on Server Fault, (a) we can already link to those things in our website field, (b) you should counteract this with some means of drawing moderator attention to these fields. But not by limiting us to whitelisted hubs.

Comment: Yes, this is the plan based on exactly that feedback. You'll be able to link to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you _very much_ then. :) I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 14):

No matter what awesome formula you are going to use to determine the *Top Tags* - somebody will always be unsatisfied with them.

Me for instance - [I do not want PHP be one of my top tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/575376) since I have no idea about it and don't even like it. Or maybe someone is totally proud of a tag having only a score of 10 on it.

Can we just make that list editable so we can just put there what we want?

I guess it should be named *Favourite Tags* then.

Comment: It's completely your own fault. You shouldn't have answered PHP questions if you're ashamed of this knowledge. :P

Comment: @Athari: Not that I'm ashamed, but I have, for example, a gold Java badge without ever having written a single Java program - just because I have been answering regex questions that happened to be tagged Java as well...

Comment: Can only support that. The fact that most OpenGL questions are for OpenGL ES doesn't magically make me an iOS or Android expert even though those belong to my top tags. I haven't ever touched a single smartphone.

Answer (score 13):

The tags section does not use the available space in an optimal way. There is too much blank space ([mentioned before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231259) by bjb568), and **long tags do not fit in a box** as seen in the screenshot below (hint: look at the [google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) tag).

The tag overview looks fancy, but unfortunately it is a bit weak on conveying information. The currently most important piece of information is missing: The number of (up)votes. It has been replaced by "% of posts", which imo is a bit redundant because you can easily estimate the % of posts by a simple calculation. Please revert back to the showing something related to votes (e.g. your rank within a tag (absolute or relative)).

> [image]

Comment: This is hilarious.

Answer (score 13):

One problem I noticed immediately is that some of my meta posts are listed in two places:

> [image]

All my posts that are in "Top Meta Posts" are also in "Top Posts from other Communities", making "Top Meta Posts" redundant except for where it displays the number of meta Qs and As.

Comment: That was just a bug, meta posts aren't supposed to show up in the top posts list. Fixed now.

Comment: Doesn't it not matter anymore with the MSO/SE split?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind. I was thinking the system treated mSO as the meta of SO, but it was a different site. Whoops, not thinking clearly... :)

Answer (score 12):

## Top tags

Considering tags are huge, they can contain more information like tag badges (100, 400, 1000 upvotes). Blocks can be colored based on percents. But they are still just wasting space.

## Top posts

I'd rather see Q and A icons colored. It's hard to distinguish them at first glance.

## About me

I don't see any point in removing *Age*. *Location* is barely readable (why `#aaa`, not `#eee`?).

And it's not clear where links below avatar come from.

## Communities

Old *Accounts* list was better. I like badges.

## Badges

Notable badges should exclude lower tiers. There's no point in showing "Epic" if the user has "Legendary". (Or "Publicist" and "Booster" in my case. I'd rather not see these random linking badges at all, if possible.) And more badges can be displayed than just three.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Ugh. Show More? I really dislike those, because it takes much more effort to click than it does to scroll down. Furthermore, this expands the "about me" all the way, so a long one pushes other important stuff downwards:

[image]

Additionally, I dislike how I have to go find the "Collapse" link to collapse it. I would prefer it if this was similar to the asking/answering questions box: with a scrollbar and the ability to increase the size:

[image]

---

Also, [the communities list has really long names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231192/218012).

[image]

I prefer the idea of taking the big favicon for the site, putting it in a box, and adding the reputation on the right. Then, the communities can be listed in a flow layout, with an immediate mouseover with the site's full name. Something like this (perhaps less grid-like or without the box; with a mouseover/expand when mouse over a site):

[image]

Comment: +1 for the collapsed sites idea

Comment: +1 because I also hate the "Show More" click... we should be able to just scroll down

Comment: Great idea! Just don't use that font ***please***. It's almost as bad as Papyrus... (at least, on sites, not mockups).

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Sorry about that. I used the ux.se mockup generator to create the box and the numbers, thinking I could add the images, but I couldn't, so I used MS Paint to finish it.

Answer (score 12):

One thing: can there be an option to change the background of it, almost like a cover photo? I made a mockup here:

[image]

A picture is worth a thousand [words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture))*. Excuse my pun. :P I think it would be a great way to add some color and personalization to a profile. Plus, <strike>moderators could mess with Jon Skeet's cover picture and change it to unicorns</strike> some people could add fun meta-themed photos!

<sub>* May be more or less than one word depending on compression, file size, computer architecture (64 vs. 32 bit), etc.</sub>

[Image source](http://www.bubblews.com/news/2497952-the-actual-facts-about-unicorns)... hope you like the mockup because I got a lot of weird looks today.

Comment: +1 for the unicorn :)

Comment: Oh yeah, no half-assed stuff, make it go real Facebook! ;-(

Comment: I agree with @ChristianRau. The whole idea of "personal profile" is wrong. The more "personal" the profile is, the worse. I'm not going to change my gravatar, no matter how ridiculous YOU are going to make it. If I'm allowed to put a background image to my profile, I'll make it a photo of my ugly buttocks in a thong. **This is not Facebook!**

Answer (score 8):

Can we have some control over which badges are displayed as "Notable"?

Or at very least, tweak the logic to give a higher priority to tag-specific badges since I feel they are ones that users are probably the most proud of.

Right now my "notable" badges are [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention), [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate), and [Pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit), none of which are very impressive.

[image]

I would much rather show off my gold [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/164/wpf) and [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/c-sharp) badges

Comment: Tag badges aren't shown right now, but should be -- we'll add that. We may also just globally exclude some badges that are rare but not very interesting (like Convention / Electorate)

Comment: @DavidFullerton Good enough for me, thanks :)

Comment: Tag badges are included now, and it turns out that my (kinda black box-ish) sorting order [granted you your wish](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UvUYD.png) :)

Comment: For me my super-rare tag badges would also be far more important in this section than generic ones, even if the latter are gold.

Answer (score 6):

Some feedback (I'll skip the positive and concentrate on improvement suggestions and/or complaints, sorry):

1. **"Notable badges" logic seems wrong**.

   Mine didn't list [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) tag gold badge - which seems more notable both conceptually, AND by rarity (37 ever awarded) - than "Booster" (1000+ awarded and not that big of an achievement).
2. Badge visualization: you can't hover over gold badges and see what they are.
3. The space utilization IMHO needs to be re-worked.

   In case of SO profile, a picture is NOT worth 1024 words.

   My Gravatar takes up 50% as much space as the "About me" text... which in turn has so little vertical space as to be almost useless.
4. Related to #3: there's too little vertical space for "About me" text - and nobody will ever read the full text if they have to click a link to expand it.
5. Top tags list takes up too much vertical space. You can squeeze 100% same design into 33%-50% less vertical space by removing margins; and free up space for #4

Comment: Your point 1 was [addressed by a question asked 16 hours before your query](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231490/133286).  The comment to that answer states that presently tag-badges are not presently included in **Notable Badges**, but will be.

Comment: Good points, but as to #4, at the moment (old profile) people have to scroll larger about me sections, too. You could argue that noone will ever read it if they have to scroll it either. Something has to be done to not make it huge by default (as there are maybe other people like me, for which it is actually too much room even in unexpanded form).

Answer (score 5):

I question the criterion of deciding what a top tag is. I think frequency of use is more meaningful to me than how much reputation has been awarded in the tag, and better reflects interest in niche topics that differentiate. Top tags is almost redundant as it stands with top individual posts anyway. My #2 tag is apparently "static" which I've only participated in twice (and I didn't pick to add that tag on those posts!). Whereas "Delphi", I've used more often than my #1 tag... But that doesn't even come close to appearing in the top tags list because it's a niche topic that doesn't get a lot of votes compared to say, Java.

Secondly, I dislike how prominently my participation on Biblical Hermeneutics (BH) (for example, top posts in other communities) shows up on the new Stack Overflow profile. I don't want my top BH posts on my Stack Overflow profile! I want my Stack Overflow profile to reflect my participation on Stack Overflow...not hobby sites, I'd prefer these less integrated, or at least an option to hide particular sites/questions from the "top sites" and "top questions" list.

Comment: The new tags section *does* use frequency (# of posts with this tag). However, it looks like there's a bug where it's only counting answers, so your #1 tag is Java instead of Delphi http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/272208/jessica-brown

Comment: Arguably, the real problem with [static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static) is that it's a bogus tag ("Hey, I need a 'static' expert! Does anyone here know 'static'?") that should be nuked and buried. But yeah, some kind of filter / opt-out / customization mechanism could be nice.

Comment: Just to follow up on the tag issue, I fixed this the other day. Delphi is now the first in your top tags. /cc @DavidFullerton

Answer (score 5):

I like the idea of the visual badge representation, a lot. But when you get to people with a lot of badges, something weird can happen:

[image]

There are quite a few more bronze badges than silver ones, yet the size of the badge-dots-area is less than half of the silver one! Even though there are actually more dots, it makes it *look* like there are lots more silver badges than bronze ones. I think this is a little odd. I think there's something going on where gold and silver badges are supposed to be bigger than the bronze dots in all cases, but on the profile you linked for someone who only had bronze badges the dots were still pretty big... So, I dunno. I get that silver badges are more important than bronze, but it just still seems strange to me for it to be SO much bigger when there's actually a lot less of them.

Comment: This is basically by-design. Those 745 silver badges are more impressive than 818 bronze badges, and so should show up larger. You still may be right that it's weird, but it is intentional.

Answer (score 5):

[If this feature suggested here (hover for badge) is implemented, we'll need to make the badges bigger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231129/190823).

The badge view looks fine with a new user:

[image]

However, when you look at Skeet:

[image]

You get the point. If the hover feature was implemented, then it would be impossible to use for some users. Although this shows me that almost six thousand badges is a lot, it makes the page much longer than necessary. And unicorns don't like bragging. I vote that we either veto this whole badge idea (I don't like this option much), or move them elsewhere. Maybe if it's too long, split it up into two columns?

Comment: I say veto it. If we can't have the pop-ups I don't want it.

Comment: The hover would likely not be enabled at the very top end of the scale (those tiny bronze badges). Also, Jon Skeet is an extreme outlier even among top users. The next highest user, [Darin Dimitrov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/29407/darin-dimitrov) has 1/4 the badges and looks pretty reasonable. We considered making one more "Jon Skeet" scale for badges but haven't done it yet.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Jon Skeet doesn't change his badges to fit the page, the developers redesign it to fit his badges ;P

Answer (score 5):

there is no link to view the user's Meta.Stackoverflow profile... I just noticed this while viewing Jon Skeet's profile...

What is this guys? Didn't expect this from SE programmers!! (lol)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Interesting. Nick Craver's apparently posted 108% of all his posts.

Under his Top Tags, 75% of posts were in jquery, and 33% of posts were in Javascript.

At first glance, this is a little bit unclear. As @Mystical points out, this is because tags overlap, but from the outside, it just looks incorrect.

Comment: Tags can overlap.

Comment: Needs one of those funky Euler diagrams

Comment: Arguably it should be *more*. Isn't anyone else wondering how it would work that 75% of the questions he answered are about jQuery, but only 33% are about JavaScript?

Comment: @balpha: Because if a question is about some specific jquery functionality, knowing just javascript and not specifically jquery isn't of much use. A `[javascript]` tag is not useful than.

Answer (score 4):

Several points I would add (I hope I don't dupe any points mentioned before):

1. I don't consider my profile text really important on SE. Currently it serves its purpose well: [my TeX.SX profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002/tohecz); in the new profile, it looks a bit strange: [me reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/1161631/tohecz). I suppose this is the case for many people. People are here to help or to get helped, so why the focus on personal info? (Btw, notice how <s>ridiculous</s> useless the gravatar is.)
2. The Q and A buttons would use some work IMHO. In large scale, they are quite indistinguishable, same shape, same colour. I think that the most important thing you want to know is whether the user excels in questions or in answers (which is not necessarily given by the number of them).

   [image]

   In small scale, they look like a circle and an up-arrow:

   [image]

   I apologize for not offering a better alternative, I'm neither an UX expert nor a designer; I just want to point out these two problems.
3. The on-mouse-over change in the community list, if it needs to change on mouse over, could be done in a bit more sensible way. Currently, the rep number jumps a mile when you mouse over it, which is quite distracting. Let's keep the rep on right and show the badges on the left of it:

   [image]

   I understand the point that the order is always *rep then badges*. If you want to keep it so, let's make the badges either shown all the time, or not shown at all.

Answer (score 4):

**BEWARE: too many changes to a good and well established interface usually lead to a WORSE interface!!! (see Micro...t's disasters, GMail changes or the recent Firefox 29 UI) !!!**

The things I don't like:

- the profile picture is too big: stackexchange is not FB or twitter
- there is too much empty space
- information boxes are not well organized and look messy
- you need one more annoying click to go to the dashboard
- the gray text is a little bit unreadable (why don't you use black for normal text???)

[image]

Comment: Too many changes don't lead to a worse interface. They lead to an interface that is different enough to the previous one that a lot of people get very vocal and complain about it. (Unless they all happen to agree it's an awful lot better, which is entirely possible.)

Comment: Well, quality of the new profiles aside, it's _definitely_ true that quantity of changes does not correlate to quality of the end result. Lots of changes does not mean a bad result, nor does few changes mean a good one. They're totally separate. What you *do* get from any radical change, especially lots at once, is complaints, simply because people hate interface changes in general almost always.

Comment: **+1** After the Firefox Whatever-it-is-now update a few days ago, I nearly switched to Chrome.

Comment: The complaints in the image you've highlighted are primarily complaints about color choice and whitespace.  This comes down to a personal preference.  You don't like the less-dense, more understated design.  I do.  This sort of binary design preference doesn't seem like it can go in a productive direction.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Usability matters. It doesn't matter what you like, using grey on white is wrong. It doesn't matter what you like, there's an optimal amount whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if Microsoft have a got a patent on this, but couldn't you just use coloured bars for the tags? Far more compact, and legible. Currently, unless someone has one or two predominant tags, it's not even immediately obvious how/that/why the sizes are different.

[image]

Oh, and I second badp's request that careers not be auto-linked (I'm having serious second thoughts about the 'connectedness' of my 'online persona' right now...)

Comment: From the question above: _"The current job and link to Careers profile are hidden for now, since they'll be optional anyway. We'll bring them back in a future version."_ You might not have to worry about it being auto-linked, unless that concern is something like the link being opt-out rather than opt-in.

Answer (score 3):

While I appreciate the consistency in styling the tags as they are styled elsewhere on Stack Overflow, the styling does look somewhat out of place.

[image: Current tag display]

I'd suggest changing this to something more suitable for such a 'modern' profile page. Perhaps something as simple as this: (I removed the 'post-tag' class, added the 'tag-style-legend' class and increased the font-size to 1em.)

[image: Proposed tag style]

While this may break some consistency within a Stack Exchange site, I do feel it looks a lot better.

Comment: This does look awesome, but I'm conflicted since the badge aesthetic is an important mental cue.

Comment: No, this does not look awesome. Why should a clearly lowercase information be displayed uppercase? Just because a designer chose so? That doesn't sound like a reason for me. Oh wait it is a reason, but then the design is a goal rather than a tool. And if I remember correctly, the goal here is to spread knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to easily get to the new user page from an old one, use [this userscript](https://github.com/TheGuywithTheHat/SE-collection/raw/master/customizations/New-user-page-linkifier.user.js) I made. It makes the user's avatar link to the new page.

> [image]

Code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New User Page linkifier
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/*
// @version      1
// @description  Links to the new user page
// @match        http://stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @grant        none
// @copyright    2014+, The Guy with The Hat
// ==/UserScript==

$(".gravatar > a[href*='http://stackoverflow.com/users/']").attr('href', $(".gravatar > a[href*='http://stackoverflow.com/users/']").attr('href').replace(new RegExp(/http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/users\/(\d+).*/),'http://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/$1'))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `// @grant none` to run the script in the page without sandbox (in order to use the page's `$`)?

Answer (score 2):

The main thing I use the existing "dashboard" for is to check for recent activity on my posts. As such I would require an "Activity" ordering for the Posts table for it to be useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

## Here's my full review:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why are you "reviewing" other parts of the page that have nothing to do with the new about me page? Also, I'm confused what you mean by the "bg-color" label on the votes tab over there. Are you also complaining that's grey?

Comment: @animuson Why not? Yes. It having a background instead of a text color, hover color, or border looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, great redesign.

The new Top Tags section however made me wince a bit. Maybe because the tags I have on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/149) have short names, but there is just too much space and not enough connective tissue holding the pieces together. Maybe a stronger border, or a more prominent background color would help better tie the right margin info together with the tag itself?

Answer (score -7):

I am not offending, I appreciate your work. Just remember one thing. When you successfully complete this and gift it to us, give us an option to revert to the old look. [image: Scrrenshot]

### UPDATE

This option is for the viewer, not the owner... It is to comfort the user who is seeing the other user's profile. So, if I click on it, then then on, every profile I see on SO, including mine, will display that way. Any other user seeing my profile would still see it their way...

## UPDATE 2

This can be maintained for a specific time period only. Say 6 months or so. Until then, the newer version can be put in beta...

Comment: I think this might be great. One can choose which look they want to see, win-win for everyone. [I don't like the new design as well, though.]

Comment: -1. It doesn't make sense. I want to access the user profiles to get some information. I might get used to seeing the information in another place, but I'll never get used to having to look at two different places depending on the person's preference.

Comment: @tohecz No, that option will set preference of the viewer, not the user... See ETA.

Comment: Why'd you title that 'ETA'? Is there a meaning for it other than estimated time of arrival I'm not aware of?

Comment: No, that would be pointless. Even gmail won't let us go back to the old look after a while. It will be waste of time to maintain the old design and keep fixing bugs related to it. Once a change is done, it's done and it's really not a big deal.

Comment: @AwalGarg [This thing!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l0BdG.jpg) From the Zelda games.

Comment: As for +10/-2 (which is now +30/-10) it's due to upvotes vs. downvotes: people who agree vs. people who disagree. (currently 3 agree, 5 disagree)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am on the fence about this for the reason you specified there. I am against it because the old version _should_ go away in favour of not having to maintain two versions. I am _for_ it, however, for _exactly_ the reason Gmail does what it does: it lets people switch back and forth between new and old versions in order to help them get comfortable with the new feature before the old one goes away forever. This is up to how the SE team wants to handle the transition, though, and what they want to do to ease people into it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, GMail DOES allow us to switch to Basic HTML look and even make it permanent. In Fact, Google Support Forum still welcomes bugs and reports of Basic HTML Look, albeit there would be very less or no bugs left now. And yes, your time-frame idea was nice. So I added it. Always good to discuss and add to answers like this. Hail SE!

Comment: @AwalGarg gmail has hundreds, if not thousands, of programmers. Billions of dollars to spend. Stack Exchange got much less. I prefer they spend their funds on other things.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree with this comment, I was just correcting your [last one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype/231404#comment760728_231404)... And I am not asking to 'maintain' the old version. Many people here like it as is. I don't think that just keeping it available for those fellow ones would take up terabytes of bandwidth. I further disagree Gmail guys would spend billions of dollars on maintaining an old abandoned version of their UI no matter how much they have in pockets. And, _other things_ Like what?

Comment: Oh yes, the old version serves some API thingy for the mobile version of GMail. I think so, because it is very similar. I don't have any proofs; if I am wrong correct me...

Comment: @AwalGarg OK, let's try a different angle. [This is how Google front page looked like back in 2005](http://web.archive.org/web/20050101091102/http://www.google.com/). Do they still offer option to revert to that look? Once they change the design of their home page, it's final. Same thing here. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Instead of looking at how Google does things, SE should see what comforts them, **and more importantly, what comforts their users**. If I say, I  want to drop college because Mark Zuckerberg dropped college and still he is rich, does it make sense? **No** because he dropped as he had FB! Google is **Google**. SE is **NOT** Google...

P.S. Its not a nice habit to change angles for the sake of giving a contradictory fact... Still good to discuss it with you guys...

Comment: I change angle because the other reached a dead end... anyway, you have full right to start feature request asking to do what you suggest here in the answer. If enough users will agree with you, I believe the team will consider this. But personally I think there will be more users against this than for this, same way this very answer got.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, the last line of the question says - _Let us know what you think!_. So is this post of mine. It is **NOT** a feature request, and I won't make one in any case. To me, it doesn't really matters how the profile page looks. Its just a profile page... As far as downvotes and opposing people are concerned, that as well doesn't really matters to me. But still, I haven't got a valid reason for why this is not a suitable option, have I?

Comment: @ShadowWizard If it's not a big deal, why changing the UI in the first place?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt dunno, not my decision but I do accept it and the team probably have good reason.