# Can we add accordions to the bio?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, markdown

As I just redid [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/190823/annonomus-penguin), I was thinking how nice it would be to have [accordions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)). I have a lot of information on it, and scrolling can make people stop reading my boring bio. Here's what I would want to do with it (snippets from my real bio here):

> ***I am a self-taught hobbyist and geek at heart who loves learning new skills and inferencing my Arduino to anything I can get my hands on.***
>
> I participated in the first Arduino.SE Area51 site launch, which failed. I got to 800 reputation there. I am now on the **[second Arduino site](http://arduino.stackexchange.com)** and am part of the Provisional Team of ♦s.
>
> [My Projects                                                                                             +]
>
> [About My Username                                                                              +]
>
> [Contact information                                                                               +]
>
> <sub>No Arduinos hurt in the making of this profile.</sub>
>
> <sub>Formerly Annonomus Person, but after being <strike>annoyed</strike> gracefully persuaded by a few users and mods, I decided to embrace my inner penguin and change my name.</sub>

As the [new profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype/231577#231577) is rolling out, I think we should add this to the bio to make the whole page look cleaner and add extra functionality.

If this is implemented, some ways it could be formatted

**HTML tag:**

```
<collapse title="My Projects">
    Foo bar.
</collapse>
```

**HTML comments (like the summary tag or code hints):**

```
<!-- title:My Projects content:Foo bar.-->
```

**Brackets:**

```
[Collapse title:My Projects][Foo bar.]
```

This one you you'd have to have to escape any "]" characters.