# What's the grey box in my Stack Overflow profile about?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the grey box under account view?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22237/what-is-the-grey-box-under-account-view)

There's a large light-grey box in the top right corner of my Stack Overflow user page, just above the "last activity: ..." info text. It's empty, non-interactive and doesn't contain advertisement or something. Is it just for decoration or does my browser miss something here? (Firefox 3.6 on Windows)

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22237/what-is-the-grey-box-under-account-view). It's a spot for your profile description, if you put anything in that field in the edit view.

Answer (score 1):

It's the closest thing Stack Overflow gets to a Facebook profile.

- Want to have your contact information visible? Put it there.
- Like long walks on the beach? That's the place to write about it.

Answer (score 0):

Its your 'About Me' if you go to edit your profile. You can put anything you;d like in there. Its not mandatory, so thats why its just a blank box for some people

A lot of people use it to post their work, and such.