# Should this box have something in it?

Tags: bug, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the grey box under account view?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22237/what-is-the-grey-box-under-account-view)

There is always an empty box on my profile in each stack. Shown here with a red border.
[image]

Shouldn't there be something there?

Comment: @jzd and @Hendrik: oh, I see. Thank you.

Comment: @Arjan, your absolutely right. It appears to be the same question. It's just hard to search for this question because it looks different on every stack and I had no idea what to call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That box shows the text from your **About Me** section on your profile.  If that field is empty then this box will be also.

Answer (score 3):

It's the "About Me" section. Hit the "edit" link in your profile to fill it out.

Answer (score 1):

[About Me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul)

If you complete all empty profile information, you will win  [Autobiographer badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/9/autobiographe) and holiday to Dubai

[image]

Comment: Only without the Dubai part.